# SharePoint Quick Launch items disappears

Tags: quick-launch

Greetings.

One of my companies costumers experience that on some of their site collections, the Quick Launch will randomly miss a few items once in a while. By iisreseting they will get restored, but that does not solve the problem, as it keeps occuring that items will disappear.

The costumer has SharePoint 2010 solution. We have no publishing features activated and the SharePoint log doesn't give us any kind of details towards why it happens.

We have experienced that this occurs after we deploy or update the costumers solution, but then we're back at the iisreset, which again leaves us as big questions marks as it still happens all random without the deploy or update to trigger it.

Comment: Are you using any audience targeting on your quick launch? Which items are being removed from the quick launch? Are they items that were auto added during the asset creation, or are they manually added or added via a feature?

Comment: Sharepoint seems to have some aggressive Caching going on, do they see the items reappear when closing the browser or clearing their cache?

Comment: @brian We added all the quick launch items ourselves.
@MichaelF The costumer hasn't informed us if they do. The support is very quick to trigger an iisreset as soon as it comes in their inbox.

Comment: Did you happen to get this resolved?

Comment: @Jerry No, never :( We are actually still facing this issue.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? We are experincing the same issue

Comment: @Paul Hi Paul. No unfortunately not. If you find out how to solve this **PLEASE** post your solution as an answer!

Comment: Just a curious to know. in your solution, is there anything that refer to navigation or overwrite it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens "at random". Are you changing any permissions when you deploy the solution(s)? That would be my first guess: that somehow the permissions for the "missing" entries have changed and therefore aren't visible. Do they disapper for everyone or some subset of people?

Comment: They disappear for everyone. When we check the Navigation in the Site Settings, even there we've experienced that they were missing.

Answer (score 1):

I was faciong the same problem.
I have 4 links to 4 Document libraries, when i click on them many times (quickly or not) they start to disappear randomly :/
Finally I found that the links target was false; I don't know who did this and how, but the links were automatically created with urls that do not exist. So when i went to the doc lib parameters deactivated and reactivated the quick launch links for the all the doc libs, it works normally.

Finally, I can say "Ich bin ein Sharepointer"

Answer (score 0):

I have found if I have subsites hidden from my parent Quick Launch, and then I modify the permissions of the subsite by clicking the "Inherit Permissions" button, then my link disappears from the parent Quick Launch. The solution is I go to my parent site and select Site Settings > Navigation > and chose "Show Subsites" and my links reappear. I then uncheck "Show Subsites" and we're back in business.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what you are talking about is the same issue I had, but it sounds similar.

I created several quick launch links in a few different groups.
If I navigated to a different page using the promoted web links, the quick launch was properly populated.
If I used any of the links I set up, then the quick launch would not display properly.  Instead I would get a single group of links.  No headers were displayed and no links from other groups were displayed.  This even occurred if I navigated back to the home page from one of the quick launch links.

What solved my issue was adding a slash "/" (without quotes) to the end of the urls.

**site/SharedDocuments**  did not work (links disappeared)

**site/SharedDocuments/** did work (all links displayed on all pages)